# redirect routes with react state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I would like to check if my cms is installed (with a api call to my backend).
I can fetch the value, I can see the "ok" value into console, but I'm not redirected to /login as expected.
I suspect `const content = useRoutes(routes(isInstalled, isLogged));` is not updated, isInstalled state, when is updated, is not send with its new value to routes.js.

App.js:

```
function App() {
  const [isLogged, setIsLogged] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isInstalled, setIsInstalled] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [client, setClient] = useState<any>();
  const content = useRoutes(routes(isInstalled, isLogged));
  const location = useLocation();

  useEffect(() => {
    const transport = createGrpcWebTransport({
      baseUrl: `http://127.0.0.1:50051`,
    });
    const client = createPromiseClient(Lucle, transport);
    setClient(client);

    if (location.pathname == "/admin") {
      check_if_installed(client)
        .then(() => {
         console.log("ok");
         setIsInstalled(true)
         })
        .catch(() => {
          console.log("NOK");
          setIsInstalled(false)
        });
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <StyledEngineProvider injectFirst>
      <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <GlobalStyles />
        {content}
      </ThemeProvider>
    </StyledEngineProvider>
  );
}
```

routes.js

```
const routes = (isInstalled: boolean, isLogged: boolean) => [
  { path: "/login", element: <Login /> },
  {
    path: "admin",
    element: !isInstalled ? (
      <Navigate to="/install" />
    ) : !isLogged ? (
      <Navigate to="/login" />
    ) : (
      <Dashboard />
    ),
    children: [
      { path: "", element: <AdminIndex /> },
      { path: "editor", element: <OnlineEditor /> },
      { path: "tables", element: <Tables /> },
    ],
  },
  {
    path: "/install",
    element: <Install />,
  },
];
```

How to update routes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigation to either of `"/login"` or `"/install"` only occurs when on the `"/admin"` route, and since both `isLogged` and `isInstalled` start out initially `false`, the UI is going to be navigated to either of `"/login"` or `"/install"` if starting from `"/admin"`. Neither `"/login"` or `"/install"` check the state and navigate anywhere else.

You basically need to implement a route protection scheme.

Here's a basic example of route protection using your state and routes.

```
import { Navigate, Outlet } from "react-router-dom";

const AnonymousRoutes = ({ isLogged }: { isLogged: boolean }) => {
  return isLogged ? <Navigate to="/admin" replace /> : <Outlet />;
};

const PrivateRoutes = ({ isLogged }: { isLogged: boolean }) => {
  return isLogged ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/login" replace />;
};

const InstalledRoutes = ({ isInstalled }: { isInstalled: boolean }) => {
  return isInstalled ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/install" replace />;
};

const UninstalledRoutes = ({ isInstalled }: { isInstalled: boolean }) => {
  return isInstalled ? <Navigate to="/admin" replace /> : <Outlet />;
};
```

```
const routes = (isInstalled: boolean, isLogged: boolean) => [
  {
    element: <AnonymousRoutes isLogged={isLogged} />,
    children: [{ path: "/login", element: <Login /> }]
  },
  {
    element: <PrivateRoutes isLogged={isLogged} />,
    children: [
      {
        element: <InstalledRoutes isInstalled={isInstalled} />,
        children: [
          {
            path: "admin",
            element: <Dashboard />,
            children: [
              { index: true, element: <AdminIndex /> },
              { path: "editor", element: <OnlineEditor /> },
              { path: "tables", element: <Tables /> }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        element: <UninstalledRoutes isInstalled={isInstalled} />,
        children: [{ path: "/install", element: <Install /> }]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Now if while any of these routes are currently rendered and the "app state" changes, the access to that route will be re-evaluated and conditionally allow the `Outlet` to be rendered and the "protected" content to be rendered ***or*** a redirect to a "safe route" is rendered. For example, if a user is unauthenticated and accesses a "ProtectedRoutes" route, they redirect to `"/login"`, and vice-versa, if they are already authenticated and attempt to access `"/login"` the UI will bounce them off that route back to `"/admin"`.

### Demo

[image: Edit redirect-routes-with-react-state]